# List all files cached by amazon cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, caching, amazon-ec2

We just started using AWS. All our images are stored on the amazon S3 Server. Now we're making thumbnails using an ec2 server with thumbor.
We added cloudfront to the ec2, to cache the images on cloudfront's edge locations, but it looks like this doesn't work. (image loading times up to 30 seconds). So, is there a way to see the cached files in the edge locations? Or to confirm that cloudfront isn't working?

Comment: Download a file that you don't think is being cached by CloudFront, and inspect the response headers.  You should see `X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront` or `X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront`, and an `Age:` header if the response is a hit.  Do you see one of these?

Comment: Hmm, I get the "Hit from cloudfront", so that can't be the problem I guess :/

Comment: The CloudFront edge locations are independent, so objects are only cached at edge locations through which they've been requested. This is not an exact duplicate of the question (at this point) but there is perhaps some useful info here on how CloudFront works: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32878535/1695906

Comment: Well, we're developing the website, so we're always requesting the information from the same location. And thanks! I'll look at it!

Comment: *"we're always requesting the information from the same location"* ah, but possibly not always through the same edge.  CloudFront's location algorithms are more clever than simple geographic distance, and connections can shift.  From Kentucky, I usually hit my sites through Virginia, and from Ohio, through Indiana... yet I have occasionally seen it switch to St. Louis or NYC for a few hours, even though my location, IP, and ISP were unchanged.

Comment: Ok. Well, i' ve read your article, and digged into the cloudfront statistics. We're using thumbor on an ec2 instance to create thumbnails from the Amazon S3, but the ec2 can't handle images with a resolution of 1800x1800, so I guess i've found the problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you (also) figure out a way to list all cached files on a cloudfront edge location ?